# How can I check PNRP settings programmatically?

Tags: wcf, pnrp

I'm trying to build an application with WCF and PNRP, but I've already run in to some problems testing on my local network, relating to the pnrp settings. Now I got this connection working locally with some command line actions to enable pnrp, but now I'm testing a connection with two applications on different networks and they simply can't find eachother and I can't figure out why.

I'd like to know if there's a way to programmatically detect if there's some issue with PNRP or at least find some useful parameters to print out to a log file so I can get the slightest idea of where the problem lies since Information about not finding peers seems to be scarce on the internet and I've tried that suggestions I did find, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at the [System.Net.PeerToPeer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.aspx) namespace as this contains some classes that allow you to programmatically reference PNRP.